# Google Auth Token for Service account is incorrect

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, service-accounts

I have created a service account with Domain Wide Delegation

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const sa = require("./credentials-ads.json");

const authUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
const scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords";

const getSignedJwt = () => {
  const token = {
    iss: sa.client_email,
    iat: parseInt(Date.now() / 1000),
    exp: parseInt(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60, // 60 minutes
    aud: authUrl,
    scope,
  };

  return jwt.sign(token, sa.private_key, { algorithm: "RS256" });
};

  const signedJwt = getSignedJwt();

  console.log(signedJwt);

  const google_token = await axios.post(
    'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
    'grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion='+signedJwt,
    {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }
);
  res.send(google_token.data);
})
```

the above giving the access_token as response but it is returned as follows:

```
{"access_token":"abcdefghijklmnopqurstuvwxyz1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmfasdfasdfasdf........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................","expires_in":3599,"token_type":"Bearer"}
```

this access token is not usable for any API call

I am trying this using HTTP/HTTPS requests in Nodejs

Was expecting to receive a usable access token, but receiving an incorrect token with .............

Comment: 1. why are you doing this manually.  2. where are you applying the delegated user?  3. How do you know its not usable? is there an error?

Comment: Note: i am extremally impressed you where able to get an access token back at all.

Comment: 1. in nodejs there isn't a library
2. I did not add the delegated user, and after reading your comment added the same and it worked!
3. with added the "sub" field while creating the JWT it gave an error saying invalid access_token

Thankyou for your appreciation and your comment that took me to the solution!

@DaImTo could you post an answer saying I am missing "sub" field I'll pick that as the answer, thanks again

Comment: There isn't a client library what about this https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference  or say https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node

Comment: I needed this for accessing Google ads API:
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs#code_examples

followed this for the same: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests

Comment: google ads api should be supported by the google apis node.js client library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For domain wide delegation you must supply the subject to delegate as.  The value of this is the email address of the user on your domain which you want the service account to impersonate.

you are probably missing sub filed.

Answer (score 0):

The multiple dots appended to the access token do not invalidate it for Google APIs and services. Google is testing larger token sizes. Ignore the fact the dots are there as the dots are padding. This allows Google to detect applications that truncate the token size.

For more information:

[OAuth 2.0 Access Token Size for Google Cloud Platform Customers](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/issues/1218)